# Python, удаление строчки в txt

Tags: python, файлы, txt

Всех приветствую, я не программист
И мало что понимаю в коде
Хочу сделать программу на python'e

**Пример**:
Есть txt файл, там например пароли
В каждой строчке по одному паролю
И если пароль меньше 7 символов(включая 7) то он должен удалить эту строчку из txt файла

Как можно это реализовать?
Пытался что-то найти, совмещал всё вместе
Но всё плохо

```
with codecs.open('users.txt','r',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f1: 
for line in f1: 
  print(line.strip()) 
  stringGET=line.strip() 
  if stringGET=='""': 
    continue 

with codecs.open('FULL LIST.txt','a',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f2: 
  f2.write(stringGET) 
  f2.write('\n') 
  f2.close
```

Comment: Построчно считываете файл. На ходу сразу после считывания проверяете длину строки и если строка больше указанной длины добавляете данную строку в переменную которая будет агрегировать и формировать новое содержание файла. по прохождению цикла у вас должна быть переменная с новым отфильтрованным содержимым, которое можно будет записать в файл.

Comment: @МихаилРебров спасибо что так расписали, но не могли бы вы показать это в коде?

Comment: @МихаилРебров я пытался так решить свою проблему

Comment: @МихаилРебров # with codecs.open('users.txt','r',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f1:
# for line in f1:
# #print(line.strip())
# stringGET=line.strip()

# if stringGET=='""':
# continue

# with codecs.open('FULL LIST.txt','a',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f2:
# f2.write(stringGET)
# f2.write('\n')
# f2.close

Comment: это хорошо что вы приложили код. Ибо у нас просто за кого-то решать задачи не принято.

Comment: я сейчас на перерыв обеденый прервусь и напишу вам ответ через полчасика

Comment: @МихаилРебров я запомню ваши слова, и благодарен вам что выделите время для решения моей проблемы

Comment: написал ответ, как и обещал. Если все заработает, то ставьте галочку слева от моего ответа (тут так принято "Спасибо" говорить)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В простейшем виде построчное чтение текстового файла выглядит вот так:

Открываем вайл для чтения

```
file = open("passwords.txt", "r")
```

> **Замечание:**
> *В данном случае предполагается, что файл passwords.txt лежит в той же папке, в противном случае указывайте в строке полный путь к файлу, каждый раз когда его открываете.*

Запускаем цикл, в котором будем построчно считывать файл

```
while True:
```

Считываем строку из файла

```
line = file.readline()
```

Если при попытке считать строку из файла мы в ответ получили `False` значит файл закончился.

Поэтому делаем проверку на окончание файл внутри цикла

```
if not line:
```

И если мы достигли конца файла, то мы выходим из цикла с помощью команды

```
break
```

далее мы закрываем файл

```
file.close()
```

Итого:

```py
file = open("passwords.txt", "r")
while True:
    line = file.readline()
    if not line:
        break

file.close()
```

Но это только начало, теперь нам нужно отфильтровать эти строки и сформировать новое содержимое файла.

Для того чтобы его было куда складывать перед началом цикла объявляем новую переменную

```
content = ""
```

далее: в цикле, после того как мы считали строку из файла нам нужно проверить длину полученной строки

```
if len(line.strip()) >= 8:
```

В данном случае мы установили проверку на длину строки большую либо равную(но точно не меньше!) 8 символов
также стоит обратить внимание на метод `.strip()`, который мы вызываем на строке
Он удаляет из строки лишние пробелы и прочие невидимые символы с начала и конца строки.
В нашем случае таким способом мы избавились от невидимого символа перевода коретки на новую строку...мы же не хотим чтобы он учавствовал в оценки длины строки, верно?

Далее: если проверка была выполнена и если очищеная от лишних невидимых символов строка не менее 8 символов, то мы прибавляем данную строку в содержимому переменной content

```
content += line
```

Оператор `+=` добавляет `line` к содержимому `content`
Эта строка эквивалентна этой

```
content = content + line
```

В итоге после прохождения цикла в переменной content у нас будут отфильтрованные строки и нам только останется их записать в файл.

Это можно сделать следующим образом

```
# открываем файл для записи
file = open("passwords.txt", "w")
# записываем значение переменной content в файл
file.write(content)
# закрываем файл
file.close()
```

Проще это сделать после того как мы вычитали весь файл и закрыли его, чтобы не путаться с курсором. Открыв файл для записи курсор автоматически сместится в начало файла и мы сможем спокойно в него писать все что надо

---

**В итоге:**

```
# чтение и формирование нового содержимого файла
file = open("passwords.txt", "r")
content = ""
while True:
    line = file.readline()
    if len(line.strip()) >= 8:
        content += line
    if not line:
        break
file.close()
# запись нового содержимого в файл
file = open("passwords.txt", "w")
file.write(content)
file.close()
```

Содержимое файла до запуска

```
U7m7aP
LJhXg2tE9
g5TXTk
WfguQE4la
0Og0qrG
bMuK1fHVY
FvfybSm
05pYQnC
sRNmuQINg
TnFOWFNPW
1d53o4
z5IKKL
RRIoYrYq
5lg0kpKnE
Z9PVQDHc
phVdjJ
hLOZFVK
PVqLJW0xm
JJvVre
ciX7hoDR
```

Содержимое файла после запуска

```
LJhXg2tE9
WfguQE4la
bMuK1fHVY
sRNmuQINg
TnFOWFNPW
RRIoYrYq
5lg0kpKnE
Z9PVQDHc
PVqLJW0xm
ciX7hoDR
```

как видим, строки которые были меньше 8 символов в длину удалились
как мы того и хотели

Comment: Благодарю что так подробно всё расписали, и конкретно показали пример

Comment: @Андрей, не за что :-)  В след. раз почитайте правила в справке [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и сам раздел [Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). У нас тут много правил. Все строго как в армии. А как известно: `Для хорошего человека армия — мать родная а для плохого — теща! ` и если их(правила) не знать, то взаимодействие с сервисом может быть не таким приятным)

Comment: @Андрей, тут очень много людей, которые готовы помочь, но большинство из них строгие :-)

Comment: Хорошо, учту в следующий раз

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо вам

Comment: @Андрей не за что :-) приятного вечера)